# .htaccess redirect not working for mobile browser

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, bluehost

```
# BEGIN Redirecting from www to non-www site
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.teachmecool\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/teachmecool\.com\/" [R=301,L]
# END Redirecting from www to non-www site
```

I am using the above code for redirection from www to non-www site. This code works fine in pc, but when I browse using mobile, its not working resulting in 'This webpage not available'.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What address does it redirect to on mobile? Is it the exact same URL as on desktop, and if so does it also give an error when you manually type it in on mobile? It seems unlikely that the redirect itself causes a different result dependin on your device

Comment: Also, you don't need to set the redirect url as a string. Replace the last rule with `RewriteRule ^/?$ http://teachmecool.com/ [R=301,L]` and see if that works better?